# Want to send parameters with custom dispatch event

Tags: actionscript-3

I am creating a library. Here is an example

```
[Event (name="eventAction", type="something")]
            public function create_new_customer(phone_number:String):void
    {
         -------------;
                     ----;
                     ------------;
          rpc.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCreate_returns);
    }

    private function onCreate_returns(evt:Event):void
    {
         var ob:Object = evt.target.getResponse();
         dispatchEvent(new something("eventAction"));
    }
```

I have a listener to this event in app side. So when I manually dispatch event I want the 
"ob" to be sent as a parameter. How to do it?

Answer (score 20):

You need to create a custom event class with extra properties to pass data with it. In your case you could use a class like

```
public class YourEvent extends Event
{
    public static const SOMETHING_HAPPENED: String = "somethingHappend";

    public var data: Object;

    public function YourEvent(type:String, data: Object, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);

        this.data = data;
    }

    override public function clone():Event
    {
        return new YourEvent (type, data, bubbles, cancelable);
    }

}
```

then when yo dispatch you do:

```
dispatchEvent(new YourEvent(YourEvent.SOMETHING_HAPPENED, ob));
```

Comment: A typo in the constructor: date should be data: public function YourEvent(type:String, date: Object ...

Answer (score 5):

In AS3 you can use DataEvent:

ex:

dispatchEvent( new DataEvent(type:String[,bubbles:Boolean=false,cancelable:Boolean=false, data:String ] );

Instead of example data, I showed the parameters DataEvent takes.

I hope this helps.

Best regards, RA.

Answer (score 0):

Make your custom event carry this `ob` object. Pass it to the custom event's ctor and voila!

Comment: thanks ... would be more helpful if i got a simple example as I am new to as!