# How can I retrieve a object from one swf file to another swf file

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I want to retrieve one object from one swf file. How can I retrieve the object? Means I am loading **one.swf** in main application. The main application is passing one session object so that object I want to retrieve is in **one.swf** file. How can I retrieve that object?  Please help me in this.

Thanks ..

Answer (score 1):

in the swf that you load in the main application you have to give an event.

question and answer: [How to raise an event from a SWF in a SWFLoader to a parent Flex application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195150/how-to-raise-an-event-from-a-swf-in-a-swfloader-to-a-parent-flex-application)

to add parameters to a dispatchevent: [Want to send parameters with custom dispatch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792451/want-to-send-parameters-with-custom-dispatch-event)